# convertir lista a int en python

Tags: python, jupyter

hola tengo esta lista = [2, 3, 5, 7] y la quiero convertir a entero cada uno de los números.
Para luego calcula el cuadrado de cada, o podría hacerlo directamente en la lista sin convertir a entero??

Comment: `lista = [2, 3, 5, 7]` > Ya es una lista de enteros, ¿Cuál es tu problema?

Comment: quiero sacarlos de la lista

Comment: Entonces necesitas [recorrer](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) la lista para obtener cada uno de ellos.

Comment: `for valor in lista: print(valor)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por lo que veo es que ya tienes una lista de enteros, puedes hacerlo con

**List comprehension**

Algo asi:

```
In [1]: lista = [2, 3, 5, 7]

In [2]: cuadrado = [n*n for n in lista]

In [3]: cuadrado
Out[3]: [4, 9, 25, 49]
```